# Why is final momentum found by two formulae in case of increasing force not equal?

Tags: applied-mechanics, kinematics

So, let us say a body moves with 10 m/s, mass = 10 kg.
At time t=0 a force of 30 N is acting on it. Gradually (linearly) the force increases and finally it becomes 130 N after a period of 2 second .

Now,  we can say that change in force every second = $30+50t.$

Now,  $dp = dt (30+50t)$

Now, integrating and putting limits as t = 0 to t= 2 seconds. We get final momentum = $160\ kg/m s^2$. Now, we cannot say that F=160/2 since value of instantaneous force is not constant.

Part 1: Finding final velocity and momentum:

If I say $130N=10*a $, then a=$13\ m/s^2.$

Final velocity = u+at = 10 + (13)(2) = 36m/s.

Now, Final momentum becomes $m*v =10*36$ = $360\ kgm/s^2.  $

Q1 Now, why is 160 not equal to 360 as the final momentum?

Q2 are final velocity and acceleration correct?

Comment: Could you clarify the following statement? "So, let us say a body moves with 10 m/s, mass = 10 kg having a force on 30 N on it. Then, let us say it’s final force acting on it becomes 130 N after 2 second ."  Is the initial velocity 10[m/s] and then a force of 30N is applied? or is the 30N required in order to move at 10[m/s]

Comment: I think your equation F = 30+50t was an incorrect start. Instead, you should write F = 30+m*a=130 and solving for a, then find V after 2s. The integration shall be performed on p = int (mv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem the you have:

- a mass moving at 10[m/s]
- at time t=0, a force of 30 [N] is applied, and  by time t=2 it increases to 130 [N]

The question is what is the final momentum.

The final momentum (at time $t_2=2[sec]$) will be equal to the initial momentum plus the impulse of the force  (see below):

$$m\cdot v_2 = m\cdot v_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t_2} F(t)dt $$

As you have gathered the force wrt time is equal to
$$F(t) = 30 +50 t$$

Therefore
$$m\cdot v_2 = m\cdot v_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t_2}  (30 +50 t)dt $$
$$m\cdot v_2 = 10 [kg] \cdot 10 \left[\frac{m}{s}\right] + \left[30t +50 t^2\right]_{t_0}^{t_2} $$
$$m\cdot v_2 = 10 \cdot 10 \left[kg \frac{m}{s}\right] + \left(30\cdot 2 +25\cdot 2^2\right) \left[N\cdot s\right]$$
$$m\cdot v_2 = \left(100 + 60 +100\right) \left[N\cdot s\right]$$
$$m\cdot v_2 = 260\left[N\cdot s\right]$$

---

The problem with the final velocity is the following:

The acceleration can be calculated by:

$$F=m\cdot a$$

Therefore:
$$ a = \frac{F(t)}{m} = 3+5t $$

So the velocity is:

$$v_2 = v_0 +  \int_{t_0}^{t_2} a(t) dt)$$
$$v_2 = v_0 +  \int_{t_0}^{t_2}  (3 +5 t)dt)$$
$$v_2 = 10 + \left[3t +2.5 t^2\right]_{0s}^{2s}$$
$$v_2 = 10 + \left(6 +10\right)$$
$$v_2 = 26 \;\frac{m}{s}$$

So finally the momemtum will be $\cdot v_2 =260 [Ns]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot . A very nice method to find answer for final momentum. Actually , the question also includes how to find final velocity and total distance covered by the body ? Where in final velocity  , I was getting wrong. I got final velocity , but we also know that acceleration keeps on changing. So , an equation for total distance covered is what I didn’t get

Comment: I have updated it. I was having trouble understanding your question what exactly the setup was so I had left it incomplete (and incorrect thanks again phil Sweet) yesterday. Anyway, I've woken up now so, and it seems I was on the right track, so I assume this is your answer.

Comment: @PhilSweet you are right. Thanks for spotting it. I was half asleep when I was posting that, and I had completed it this morning.

Comment: @NMech Ohh. I just couldn’t think to find acceleration that way. I’ll keep it in mind. Thanks a lot

Comment: When you wrote m.v2  = mv1 + integration of 30+50t. Then , what happened to the constant of integration ?

Comment: I know after a long time but got stumbled upon a small point.

Comment: Oh. I got it. Constant of integration =0.

Answer (score 1):

I see this problem differently.

The 10kg mass was moving at a constant speed at 10 m/s, so $V_0 = 10 m/s$. 2 seconds After a 30N force was applied, the force increased to 130N due to acceleration, this can be expressed as $a = (F_2 - F_1)/m = (130 - 30)/10 = 10 m/s^2$. Now we can find the final velocity, $V_F = V_0 + a*t = 10 + 10*2 = 30 m/s^2$.

For $V_0 = 10 m/s$ and $V_F = 30 m/s$

$p = m*(V_0 + V_F) = 10*(10 + 30) = 400 kg*m/s$

***Edit: Adding figure below.***
[image]

Comment: Isn’t it that by writing 10m/s^2 as your acc. You have assumed that acc is 10 throughout the journey of 2seconds whereas it is (Given in the Q)3m/s^2 at t=0 sec and then increased 13m/s^2.

Comment: No, it moves at a constant speed with a = 0, then a sudden blow of 30N (gulf swing) forced it to speed up that increases the velocity, thus acceleration a = (Vf - V0)/t. That's my argument, the mass does not have initial acceleration, the 30 N force is externally applied, not due to moving, because prior to that moment F = ma = 10*0 =0. .

Comment: @Srijan I added a figure. I think you need to set up the reference timeline, and realize that with constant speed prior to time 0, both the acceleration and force equal to zero, because the object can't accelerate itself, so F = m*a = 0 at t = 0- until the external force is applied.at t = 0+. that triggers the acceleration, thus at t = 2s, F = 30 + m*a = 130N. Hope you got the picture.

Comment: Your point is also making sense. Nice one.

Comment: @Srijan The argument really depends on the initial force whether it causes immediate acceleration or not. I am trying to get to the bottom of it too.

Comment: @Srijan Please review the linked articles that might help you.  https://www.livescience.com/46560-newton-second-law.html, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_(physics)

Comment: Ohk. Thanks a lot. I’ll check them for sure. I have posted a new Q. Do check it